# Difference between Phenomenal and Phenomenological in the Context of Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology, measurement-problem, foundations

I was going through a conference presentation on System of Systems Engineering. In the presentation entitled **"Macroscopic Quantum Mechanics and the SoSE Design Approach"**, I came across a slide distinguishing classical observation as a phenomenal and quantum observation as phenomenological.

This is the slide which i am talking about:
[image]
I would like to know the difference between these two in the context of physics.

> Links to Presentation and Outline:
>
> Abstract : https://iitk.ac.in/eeold/archive/courses/2009/system_of_systems/indous2/topics.html#T21
>
> Outline: http://insist.ac.in/images/publication/pub-2009-02abs.pdf
>
> Presentation: https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/52736479/and-the-sose-design-approach

This is quite a broad question but I would like to know different answers from different fields in physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two terms are more philosophical than physical. This is to say that, although philosophy plays an important role in *interpreting* physical phenomena, neither term has a precise meaning in physics, and there will be necessarily divergent opinions expressed on this site.

**Phenomenological**  in physics usually refers to building mathematical models with primary stress on correctly describing the observed phenomena (experimental measurements), rather than constructing models from the first principles. The most well-known example is thermodynamics and statistical mechanics: thermodynamics is a phenomenological theory relating several macroscopic quantities (pressure, volume, temperature, etc.), whereas statistical mechanics is trying to derive the thermodynamical laws from the microscopic equations of motion. Landau theory of phase transitions, London equations for superconductors, Laughlin's theory of quantum Hall effect are all examples of phenomenological theories - they postulate some properties (like Landau free energy or Laughlin wave function) which allow deriving correct relations between measured macroscopic quantities. In some cases (and usually later chronologically) these postulates can be justified by microscopic derivations.

*Quantum theory is phenomenological in the sense that it postulates laws and equations that are not directly observable.* As such, one could, in principle, formulate quantum mechanics using a completely different mathematical approach, as long as it produces the same results (in fact, originally the Heisenberg's matrix mechanics and Schrödinger's wave mechanics were two competing theories). One however rarely refers to quantum theory as phenomenological nowadays, reserving the term for the description of macroscopic properties.

**Phenomenal** means perceptible through senses and immediate experience, which quantum mechanics is clearly not. In the context described in the question phenomenological is referred to this aspect of QM: not directly observable, but conjectured to explain the observations.

Comment: But isn't then all theories phenomenological? I mean what differentiates Hamiltonian, Lagrangian or Newtonian mechanics? All of them try to correctly described observed phenomena.

Comment: @Anton usual opposition is between *phenomenological* and *microscopic* theories - this obviously makes sense only when talking about *macroscopic* phenomena. Regarding Newtonian vs. Lagrangian mechanics, one could say that in the latter the equations-of-motion are derived from a postulated least action principle, whereas in the former they are simply a result of many observations.

Comment: Couldn't we say that Newton's second law act as a postulate?

Comment: @Anton Why only the second? They're all postulates

Comment: Yes, that is why I am asking.  If thermodynamics can be postulated, the reason why it is called phenomenological is the fact that it doesn't start from a microscopic description? If we view all theories as different sets of axioms (postulates) then such a distinction (phenomenological) doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Anton I think *phenomenological* is opposed to something derived from basic/elementary principles: in case of thermodynamics it is microscopic derivation, whereas in case of mechanics it is derivation in terms of basic symmetries of space-time. In either case it is really more a philosophical than physical distinction.