# Do things and people in the macro world maintain a quantum decoherence? Or do you repeat quantum coherence and quantum decoherence every moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence, coherence

Does quantum decoherence remain uninterrupted for things and people in the macro world? Does the interaction of particles occur permanently without interruption in the macro world? Is that why our bodies consistently have particle properties?
Do things and people in the macro world maintain a quantum decoherence? Or do you repeat quantum coherence and quantum decoherence every moment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do things and people in the macro world maintain a quantum decoherence? Or do you repeat quantum coherence and quantum decoherence every moment?

Comment: Perhaps this will answer your question (or help to formulate it clearer): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567596/247642

Comment: sorry. I can not understand. Quantum decoherence is that particles interact with each other. So, in reality, all 10^28 subatomic particles in our body are constantly interacting with the environment without interruption?